# Selenium AndroidDriver - Unable to switch to iframe "Cannot read property 'document' of undefined"

Tags: ruby, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I'm unable to switch over to the iframe inside of AndroidDriver. The details are below.  I've tried with the regular webdriver using firefox and i'm able to switch over just fine.

Code:

```
require "selenium-webdriver"
require "selenium/client"

include Selenium::WebDriver::DriverExtensions::HasTouchScreen

caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.android
client = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Http::Default.new
client.timeout = 480
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for(
  :remote,
  :url => "http://localhost:8080/wd/hub",
  :http_client => client,
  :desired_capabilities => caps)

driver.navigate.to "some page with iframe"

driver.switch_to.frame "engagement-iframe"
```

Stacktrace:

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError: Error: {"message":"Cannot read property 'document' of undefined"}
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'armv7l', os.version: '3.0.31-789635', java.version: '0'
Driver info: driver.version: AndroidWebDriver (org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException)
    from [remote server] org.openqa.selenium.android.library.AndroidWebDriver(AndroidWebDriver.java):997:in `throwIfError'
    from [remote server] org.openqa.selenium.android.library.AndroidWebDriver(AndroidWebDriver.java):868:in `executeRawScript'
    from [remote server] org.openqa.selenium.android.library.AndroidWebDriver(AndroidWebDriver.java):858:in `access$7'
    from [remote server] org.openqa.selenium.android.library.AndroidWebDriver$AndroidTargetLocator(AndroidWebDriver.java):679:in `frame'
    from [remote server] org.openqa.selenium.support.events.EventFiringWebDriver$EventFiringTargetLocator(EventFiringWebDriver.java):573:in `frame'
    from [remote server] org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.SwitchToFrame(SwitchToFrame.java):52:in `call'
    from [remote server] org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.SwitchToFrame(SwitchToFrame.java):1:in `call'
    from [remote server] java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync(FutureTask.java):305:in `innerRun'
    from [remote server] java.util.concurrent.FutureTask(FutureTask.java):137:in `run'
    from [remote server] org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$1(DefaultSession.java):151:in `run'
    from [remote server] java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor(ThreadPoolExecutor.java):1076:in `runWorker'
    from [remote server] java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java):569:in `run'
    from [remote server] java.lang.Thread(Thread.java):856:in `run'
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem with my tests, I am guessing that this behaviour will reproduce on ChromeDriver.

My workaround (an ugly workaround) was to treat the iframe as an independent window.

It'll be great to hear your solution for this WebDriver bug

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I've noticed many users have the same issue.  I'll definitely report back if I come across a solution